# Facebook login is not working. Worked last time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to login via Facebook SDK and retrieve user's fb id via Graph. Here is the implementation:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* Facebook Authentication  */
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // set permission list, Don't forget to add email
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info", "email"));

    // session state call back event
    authButton.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                         Exception exception) {

            Log.i(TAG, session.toString());
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                // not accessed
                Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            Log.d("Social", user.getId());
                            // not accessed
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    }); // Facebook Auth end
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Facebook Login Button in layout:

```
        <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/authButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            fb:login_text="Login with Facebook"
            fb:logout_text="Logout" />
```

Everything worked fine. I can see the blue login button. But when I press login, it returned this line:

```
{Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:xxxxx}
```

I've already set the Keyhash in settings and the App ID is correct.

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.7. Before this it worked. After Facebook updated its SDK it doesn't work anymore.

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Is there any error or warning log from logcat that you can upload ? It would be really helpful.

Comment: There is no errors whatsoever. I only pull the information via Logcat to see what's inside `session`.

Comment: I only want to obtain the user facebook id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heh, silly mistake.

Instead of Overriding `onActivityResult` in the Fragment, I have to put it inside MainActivity that hosts the fragment.

Inside MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```